# XPath loop with Selenium and perl

Tags: perl, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to extract all name values in input fields using selenium and perl.  Part of the value, enough to identify it, is known, the rest is unknown:

This xpath works in finding all relevant matches:

```
//tr/td//input[contains(@name,'partofname')]
```

So, in perl:

```
my $xpath = qq(//tr/td//input[contains(\@name,'partofname')]);
my $count = $sel->get_xpath_count($xpath);
```

Fine, $count gives a suitable count of matches.

However, how to extract the value of the @name attribute for each individual matches?

I understand the principle is to construct a loop:

```
foreach my $row (1 .. $count) {
#extract here
};
```

However, I can't seem to construct an xpath expression which will work to find each $row that the expression matched.  So I think it's the correct xpath expression to get each individual match that I need help with.

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try `//tr/td/descendant::input[contains(@name,'partofname')][1]`

Replace `1` with your counter. If that doesn't could you add some HTML to your question so I can perhaps suggest a better XPath?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion but this produced:

    Invalid xpath [2]: //tr/td/descendant::input[contains(

for each node.

The html is just a table, with rows and a few table data entries for each row - one of which contains input attributes including name, id etc.

Comment: A snippet of your HTML would still be useful.

Comment: What minimum sized snippet would be useful?  Table is rather big, as is each row - would one row with several <td> tags, one of which contains the sought after attributes, do?

Comment: It's really just for the structure of your HTML, so just a couple of dummy rows would be fine. I just want to make sure I can test whatever solution I might be able to provide.